# setting cookie in golang

Tags: javascript, vue.js, go, cookies

I have a Vue.js app that makes a login request (POST) to a golang server. I set the cookie as shown below.I get a successful response back from the server. However when I look for the cookie in the browser settings I cant find it. Do I need to get the response and use java-script to set the cookie?

```
    expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    cookie    :=    http.Cookie{Name: "csrftoken",Value:"abcd",Expires:expiration}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

    json,_json.Marshal(response)
    w.write(json)

     return
```

Comment: You probably want to set the cookie [Path](https://godoc.org/net/http#Cookie.Path) to "/".   The application must set the cookie before [WriteHeader](https://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter.WriteHeader) is called (either directly or indirectly).  It will help if you show your actual code in the question.

Comment: Also please use MaxAge instead of Expires.

Comment: Seems that if you want to access cookies from JS they must be not HttpOnly. That fact creates much bigger security hole. CSRF protection can be implemented in some other way in Vue+Go app.

Comment: are the vuejs app and the go server running under the same domain? or do they have their own webservers each?

Comment: @Tornike im currently using localhost:8080 for the vue app and the Rest Api i call in the vue app is at localhost:8082

Comment: @Julia12 I think that could be a problem, cookies are attached to one domain and cannot be used by other domain